# BMW E90 318d oil leak

Tags: oil, diesel, leak, oil-leak, 320d

I've recently replaced my splash shield and I found some oil spots on the oil pan. I've tried to look for the highest point where I could find leaked oil and it seemed to be near the oil filter housing. My oil level seems to be constant but the oil drip doesn't seem to be old therefore I'm wondering if it could be a fresh oil leak. Maybe it's the oil filter housing gasket that need to be replaced? I've took some pictures from underneath the engine and from above right next to the oil filter. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

picture taken next to the oil filter housing:
[image]

picture taken next to the oil filter housing:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really it's impossible to tell from the pictures, it could be an old leak or it could be recent. As it is obviously not a big leak you're best bet would be to clean the area so it's clear of oil and then see if you get more oil. If you do, you know you still have a leak, and cleaning the area will help you trace it back to the source.

Comment: Right! One way to find a leak is to change an old leak to a new one, if it is there at all.

Comment: I recently changed the oil to a nearby car service and the oil dipstick is 2 mm above the high mark. Maybe they slightly overfilled the engine with oil. What happens when there is way too much oil in a car engine? Could this cause any oil leaks?

Comment: 2mm over is nothing @OctavianVladu , well within tolerance. You'd have to really overfill before you have problems.